# Django allauth got an error is_safe_url() got an unexpected keyword argument 'allowed_hosts'

Tags: django, django-allauth

I am trying to setup Django social login using allauth tutorial [here](https://wsvincent.com/django-allauth-tutorial/). I am able to display login page, but when I try login using facebook provider in this url `http://localhost/accounts/facebook/login/`, I got this confusing error:

`TypeError at /accounts/facebook/login/ is_safe_url() got an unexpected keyword argument 'allowed_hosts'`

Any suggestion for this issue?

Comment: Which version of django are you using? I suggest taking a look at `django.utils.http.is_safe_url()`

Comment: Django 1.10. Okay, checking

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the clue @bdoubleu! Just realize that the issue was clearly because changes in the lib. Changing Django version to 1.11 solved this issue. Thanks!